# Angular 2 - Won't load (no error)

Tags: node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6, angular

Trying to initiate angular 2 with basic hello world template. This is my **boot.js** which is transpiled to es5 later on:

```
import {bootstrap, Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'articles'
})
@View({
  template: 'Hello from angular'
})
class application{

}

bootstrap(application);
```

This is my **index.jade** which extends layout.jade with all required scripts:

```
extends layout

block content
  //CONTENT
  .container(style="margin-top:20px")

    articles      // <--- ---------------angular app
      h1 
        i(class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin') 

  //END CONTENT
```

Console does not show any errors, but the app is still not loading correctly.

Included scripts in **layout.jade**

```
script(src='https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js')
script(type="text/javascript", src="/js/angular-build/boot.js")
```

Traceur transpiler in my gulp file:

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
    return gulp.src(angular_dirs.src)
        .pipe(traceur({
            modules: 'instantiate',
            annotations: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(angular_dirs.dest));
});
```

I am using latest angular 2 installed with npm. I have also included few other devDependencies:

```
"es6-promise"
"es6-shim"
"reflect-metadata"
"rxjs"
"systemjs"
```

Comment: use `import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';` and `import {component} from 'angular2/core'`

Comment: That's a super old version of systemjs, you should update it.

Comment: angular.io needs to be updated =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It the later builds of Angular 2, you can no longer import things from `'angular2/angular2'`.  You need to pull them in from their proper packages.

For example, to import `Component` you would do:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

The `angular2/angular2` package was removed in Alpha 53, as you can see in the [Changelog entry](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-2) in the **Breaking Changes** section.